# How do I make my computer recognize my old hard drive

Tags: data-recovery

Ok so.... I had to wipe my computer clean of everything because of bad malware that completely locked me out of safe mode and my computer itself. So I wiped my MAIN hard drive clean, and I can see my other internal hard drive that contains my important files through connected to my computer.

If I go into My computer through the manage option via right click, and go to disk management, I can see my hard drive is connected to my computer. It even says the hard drive is healthy, I can see at least 100GB are being used on the hard drive which means it still contains my files, unless I'm mistaken. I thought I might be able to format it, but when I attempt to format it, it tells me that I cannot format the partition on that disk.

I would greatly appreciate help, and any possible solutions, I've already searched around but some of the options I have found I don't really have access too, and I'm afraid to do anything without some more experienced help. I'm getting a bit frustrated considering my valuable files are on that hard drive, most of them are game files that I've spent a lot of time on, and would rather not loose.

Thank you for your time and help, I appreciate all help.

Comment: What happens when you right click on the drive?

Comment: wait, are you saying you have files you want to keep on the same drive you want to format? or am I misunderstanding? formatting will destroy the data on the volume, so you don't want to format a volume if it has files you want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

If your drive is showing up in Disk Management but not in Windows Explorer, try this:

1. In Disk Management right-click the partition or drive and select **Change Drive Letter and Paths**.
2. Assign a drive letter by selecting **Add**, click the letter that you want to use, and then click OK.

Comment: Yup....I figured it out like 30min ago and boy do I feel stupid. Thank you though, at least you guaranteed me fixing the issue. lol